# Pipe Unix Socket to a random TCP socket using Python and may be Socat

Tags: python, sockets, socat

I want to pipe a TCP socket to Unix socket
I could do this using socat like this

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:1234 UNIX-CONNECT:test.socket
```

But the problem here, I don't want to specify the port number myself
I want the OS to choose a free port for me, yet I can still know the port.

I wrote this script, that doesn't work, but may illustrate what I want to do

```
def bind(unix_sock_file):
    tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_socket.bind(('', 0))
    tcp_socket.listen(1)
    cmd = 'socat - UNIX-CONNECT:%s' % unix_sock_file
    Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=tcp_socket, stdout=tcp_socket, close_fds=True)
    return tcp_socket.getsockname()
```

The error I got is:

> 2012/09/11 15:34:39 socat[26509] E read(0, 0x1e97a90, 8192): Transport
>   endpoint is not connected

Note#1: I accept any other solution other that socat too
Note#2: This script should pipe a Web Server listening on the Unix Socket, and a Web Browser connecting to the generated TCP port.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I added the error msg to the end of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simpler way to it, here it is:

```
def bind(unix_sock_file):
    CMD = "socat TCP-LISTEN:0 UNIX-CONNECT:%s" % unix_sock_file
    pid = Popen(CMD, shell=True, close_fds=True).pid
    return psutil.Process(pid).get_children()[0].get_connections()[0].local_address[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [socket.getsockname()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) to get the port number, like this (tried in iPython):

```
In [7]: tcp_socket.getsockname()[1]
Out[7]: 41605
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this is not the problem!

Comment: Ah, you've included it now in your script. But don't you have to include the port in your ``socat`` command instead of returning it in your function? And what is exactly your problem if you state: 'But the problem here, I don't want to specify the port number myself I want the OS to choose a free port for me, yet I can still know the port.'

Comment: My problem is stated in the title, "Pipe Unix Socket to a random TCP port"
The problem is that I want to lauch socat to a random port, and still I should be able to know the port later

Comment: I could run "socat TCP-LISTEN:0 UNIX-CONNECT:test.socket" which works, I won't be able to know the port programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `UNIX-CONNECT` with `UNIX-LISTEN`.  With CONNECT, you are trying to connect to a socket that exists; which it doesn't so it faults.  If I understand what you want, you want this code to create a new UNIX socket.

Change:

```
cmd = 'socat - UNIX-CONENCT:%s' % unix_sock_file
```

To:

```
cmd = 'socat - UNIX-LISTEN:%s' % unix_sock_file
```

Comment: I am sorry if my explanation is bad, but the Unix socket is created and being listened to by a Web Server.
I want this script to connect to this socket, and Listen to a TCP socket. To enable a browser to connect to the Web Server

Comment: @Radian oh ok- then i think 'Transport endpoint is not connected' means the webserver isn't running or otherwised closed the socket; but hasn't removed the socket file.